# How to solve a 2 variable linear simultaneous equation? Java

Tags: java, math

Say you have

```
3x + 2y = 11 
2x - 3y = 16
```

How would you work out `x and y` in Java?

After doing some algebra I figured out that `x = de-bf / ad-bc` and `y = af-ce / ad-bc`

These show what the letters are
`a + b = e` and `c + d = f`

Whenever I write the code it always gives me the wrong answer, I am not sure if that is due to using int instead of doubles or what. Would it also be possible to parse the letters from the equation e.g

```
input: 5x - 3y = 5
parased as: a = 5, b = -3 and e = 5
```

Here is the code without parsing

```
public static void solveSimultaneousEquations(double a, double b, double c, double d, double e, double f) {
    double det = 1/ ((a) * (d) - (b) * (c));
    double x = ((d) * (e) - (b) * (f)) / det;
    double y = ((a) * (f) - (c) * (e)) / det;
    System.out.print("x=" + x + " y=" + y);
}
```

Comment: Where is your code? What is your specific question? *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).*

Comment: Please ashow us your code. And yes, you should use double instead of int.

Comment: You ask if using int instead of double might cause your problem. I bet it would take you less time checking that than asking here. You would know the solution much faster than waiting for answer here. BTW. You must use parentheses in your equations for solving x and y.

Comment: Please use a debugger and print calls to debug your code. Also, look into the concept of Unit Tests.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you divide your determinant twice!

your formula is

```
x = de-bf / ad-bc
y = af-ce / ad-bc

det = ad-bc
```

so:

```
x = de-bf / det 
y = af-ce / det
```

But you calculate:

```
double det = 1/ ((a) * (d) - (b) * (c));
```

so in your program `det` is not `det` from the formula, but `1/det`!

So either you correct:

double det = ((a) * (d) - (b) * (c));

*or*

double x = ((d) * (e) - (b) * (f)) * det;
   double y = ((a) * (f) - (c) * (e)) * det;

I prefer the first one:

```
public static void solveSimultaneousEquations(double a, double b, double c, double d, double e, double f) {
    double det = ((a) * (d) - (b) * (c));  //instead of 1/
    double x = ((d) * (e) - (b) * (f)) / det;
    double y = ((a) * (f) - (c) * (e)) / det;
    System.out.print("x=" + x + " y=" + y);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Matrices is the easiest way to solve systems of equations

So, from your example:

3x + 7y = 41
5x - 3y = 25

You can actually create matrices

[[3 7]
 [5 -3]]

and

[41 25]

Now, if you multiply both sides by the inverse of the left side matrix, you will have

[[1 0]
[0 1]]

on the left side, and the solution for both x and y on the right side

there used to be a matrix package that NASA had developed and made available where you could create matrices and do inverses. Look for that or something similar

Comment: This is what I was trying to accomplish, after working out using letters instead of numbers I came to my equations which I know work because I have tested them. Thanks for the NASA suggestion I will look into that

Comment: You don't need to look to NASA.  There are Java libraries to do this, including Apache Commons Math.  http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/