# LibGDX coordinates of intersection points between a Line Segment and a Circle

Tags: java, libgdx

I'm working with LibGDX and I have a Line Segment (x1, y1, x2, y2) intersecting a circle with the center (cx, cy) and a radius R.

How can I determine the coordinates of the intersection points using LibGDX (or pure Java)?

I'm checked the **`Intersector.intersectSegmentCircle`** method, but this return only `true` or `false` without return the intersection points coordinates.

[image: Example]

I thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's my solution.

Basically a parametric equation of the line is found, then each coordinate is replaced in the equation of the circle, and we solve for `t` using the quadratic formula. The values obtained are used to get the points coordinates. See the answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/311956/515717) for a more in-depth explanation of the math. Additionally, since the line is not infinite in this case, a check is made to see if the intersection points obtained fit in the same rectangle that the line fits in.

I used the same symbols that you use in the figure.

```java
public class Intersections {

    /**
     * Returns a list of intersection points between the edge of a circle and a line.
     * @param cx Circle center X coordinate.
     * @param cy Circle center Y coordinate.
     * @param r Circle radius.
     * @param x1 First line X coordinate.
     * @param y1 First line Y coordinate.
     * @param x2 Second line X coordinate.
     * @param y2 Second line Y coordinate.
     * @return A list of intersection points.
     */
    public static List<Vector2> getCircleLineIntersectionPoints(
            float cx, float cy, float r, float x1, float y1, float x2, float y2) {
        // Find values to use in quadratic formula
        float dx = x2 - x1;
        float dy = y2 - y1;
        float a = dx * dx + dy * dy;
        float b = 2 * dx * (x1 - cx) + 2 * dy * (y1 - cy);
        float c = (float) Math.pow((x1 - cx), 2) + (float) Math.pow((y1 - cy), 2) - r * r;
        float d = b * b - 4 * a * c;  // Discriminant

        ArrayList<Vector2> points = new ArrayList<>();
        if (d >= 0) {
            // Perform quadratic formula to get 2 points
            float root = (float) Math.sqrt(d);
            float t1 = 2 * c / (-b + root);
            float t2 = 2 * c / (-b - root);

            // Need the rectangle bounds that the line fits in to check
            // if intersection points are within the line bounds
            float xmin = Math.min(x1, x2);
            float ymin = Math.min(y1, y2);
            float xmax = Math.max(x1, x2);
            float ymax = Math.max(y1, y2);

            // Add first point
            float p1x = x1 + dx * t1;
            float p1y = y1 + dy * t1;
            if (isPointInRectangle(xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax, p1x, p1y)) {
                points.add(new Vector2(p1x, p1y));
            }

            // Add second point if there's one
            if (!MathUtils.isEqual(t1, t2)) {
                float p2x = x1 + dx * t2;
                float p2y = y1 + dy * t2;
                if (isPointInRectangle(xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax, p2x, p2y)) {
                    points.add(new Vector2(p2x, p2y));
                }
            }
        }
        return points;
    }

    private static boolean isPointInRectangle(
            float xmin, float ymin, float xmax, float ymax, float px, float py) {
        return px >= xmin && py >= ymin && px <= xmax && py <= ymax;
    }
}
```

Note that this fails and returns no points if both line points are the same but on the edge of the circle. I didn't test it much so make sure it works for all your cases.

EDIT: Instead of checking whether points are in the rectangle, it would be possible to check if the `t` values are between 0 and 1. However `x1`, `y1`, `x2`, `y2` would need to be replaced with `xmin`, `ymin`, `xmax`, `ymax` everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Not really an answer yet too long for a comment and using formatting that is only available for answers.

To find the intersecting points, mathematically, you need to solve two simultaneous equations. One for the circle and one for the straight line.

You can easily find the forms of these equations by searching the Internet.

- Circle: (x - h)<sup>2</sup> + (y - k)<sup>2</sup> = r<sup>2</sup>
- Line: y = mx + c

You can find the equation of a straight line given two points on the line and you claim to have two such points.

You also claim to have all the data for the circle, i.e. the co-ordinates of the circle's center plus the length of its radius.

You then need to search the Internet for how to solve simultaneous equations in java. I found this SO question:
[How to solve a 2 variable linear simultaneous equation? Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42279579/how-to-solve-a-2-variable-linear-simultaneous-equation-java)